# How can I insert values to msi table

Tags: c#, wix, windows-installer, custom-action

I'm using Wix for intalling application & service, and I want to change the values in the msi table(session.database).

I tried to do it with a custom action, I can select values from the table using select statement, but if I try to insert, the setup fails.

My code:

```
 [CustomAction]
 public static ActionResult MyCustomAction1(Session session)
 {
     ServiceController serviceController = new ServiceController(serviceName);

     //-----Works fine-----
     res=session.Database.ExecuteIntegerQuery("select ServiceType from ServiceInstall where StartType=4");

     //----Makes the setup fail
     session.Database.Execute("insert into ServiceInstall (ServiceInstall) values ('a')");       
     return ActionResult.Success;
  }
```

Is it possible to insert values with custom action?

Thanks

---

Thank you' I've tried this:
session.Database.Execute("insert into ServiceInstall (Name) values  ('ezm') TEMPORARY");

But I get the folloing exception:
Exception:Function failed during execution. Database:  Table(s) Update failed.

Answer (score 1):

You can only insert temporary data into the MSI database at install time. There's a special syntax for this - `INSERT INTO {table} ({column-list}) VALUES ({constant-list}) [TEMPORARY]`. Pay attention to the last word - although it is optional, it MUST be present if you try to insert data from custom action.

Comment: Thank you' I've tried this: session.Database.Execute("insert into ServiceInstall (Name) values ('ezm') TEMPORARY");

But I get the folloing exception: Exception:Function failed during execution. Database: Table(s) Update failed.

Comment: Make sure you specified all required fields of the ServiceInstall table